# Python: Confused with multi-processing

Tags: python

I Mostly would like some clarification or explanation... the below script will start 4 different instances of the "pwd_find" function... if the arguments names of the "pwd_find" match that of "break_points" dictionary keys (start, stop, pause) ... "pwd_find" function will run normally, HOWEVER, when i changed the last argument (or any) name of "pwd_find" to not match the ones of the dictionary, the whole function will not run... anyone can explain why this happens? as i thought that parameter name do not matter ... ?

````
cores = 4
wordlist = []


def pwd_find(start, stop, pa):
    print (pa)

for pw in passwordList:
    wordlist.append(pw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    break_points = []
    for i in range(cores):
        break_points.append({"start":math.ceil(len(wordlist)/cores * i), "stop":math.ceil(len(wordlist)/cores * (i + 1)), "pause": 123})

    p = Pool(cores)

    for i in break_points:
        a = p.apply_async(pwd_find, kwds=i, args=tuple())

    p.close()
    p.join()```
````

Comment: Argument names matter if you're passing arguments *by* their names, which you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're passing all the arguments as keyword-only arguments via the `kwds=i` parameter here:

```
p.apply_async(pwd_find, kwds=i, args=tuple())
```

Where `i` is that dictionary `{"start": ..., "stop": ..., ...}`.

The names of parameters do matter when you're referring to them by name:

```
print("Hello", "world", sep=", ")
```

Here one such argument must be called `sep`, and if you mistype it, you'll get an error